# What do they call “all the provisions provided during the launch campaign or atmospheric re-entry of a spacecraft“ in the context of astronautics?

Tags: spacecraft, reentry, terminology, safety

I am reading an entry in a French dictionary and translating it into English. This entry is “sauvegarde.” In a general context, this term is translated as “safeguard,” “protection,” or even “conservation.” However, in the context of astronautics, the definition essentially says, “All the provisions provided during the launch campaign or atmospheric re-entry of a spacecraft in order to ensure the safety of people and goods in terrestrial, maritime and airspaces.”

Now, my knowledge of astronautics is sorely lacking, which is why I am not sure if “safeguard” really is the word that goes with that definition.

What is the word that matches the above definition?

Comment: It might be useful if you could include the sentence with that word in it so we can see the context in which it is being used - the initial French & then your translation so far.  My initial thoughts were something along the lines of, or having to do with "check list", but I might be misinterpreting the context.

Comment: @Fred: Well, I have some good news and some bad news. The bad news is that I have not been able to find sentences that have “sauvegarde” in that context in them. The good news is that I have found a French dictionary listing definitions for “sauvegarde.” (https://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/Resultat.aspx) For the definition listed above, it translates “sauvegarde” as “safety range.” However, my research indicates that it probably should be “range safety.” I hope this helps!

Comment: It sounds to me as if you've solved it yourself. Consider writing an answer. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_safety